# Microsoft Mediaroom ADK 3.0.3.3 boundlist trouble

Tags: simulator, adk

i would like to ask, if someone had encountered problem with Microsoft Mediaroom ADK version 3.0.3.3. I am trying to create application using Boundlist as vertical list, which gets data from xml file.

But when I set attribute "VisibleItemCount" to value 1 or 2 and my xml file contains more than 5 entries, which I need to display, I encounter a problem that I am not able to fix.
When I reach the last entry, I am still able to push "down" button on remote, which will get me to the first entry again, when I push it again, its still stuck at the first entry.

I was trying to debug my application with Simulator Console, but what I got suprised me: the client asks for more entries, than XML contains, e.g. last entry is at index 5, but client asks for more : "XMLFile.xml?startIndex=12&itemCount=1&direction=Down"

Important code in my project:
MRML file:

```
<mrml:TVXmlDataSource ID="_menu" runat="server" AutoLoad="false" Style="position: absolute;
        top: 514px; left: 2px;" Url="XMLFile.xml">
</mrml:TVXmlDataSource>
<mrml:TVBoundList ID="TVBoundList1" runat="server" Style="position: absolute; left: 1px; width: 636px; top: 60px; height: 353px;" 
            AutoFlow="Vertical"  ScrollUpArrowUrl="file:///Arrow_Scroll_up.png" 
            ScrollDownArrowUrl="file:///Arrow_Scroll_Down.png" ArrowHeight="20" ArrowWidth="20" 
            DataBinder="XmlDataBinder,_menu," ListCounterID="TVLabel10" 
            VisibleItemCount="1">
            <mrml:TVListItemTemplate ID="TVListItemTemplate1"
                FocusGlow="ARGB(40,227,0,115)" FocusBackground="ARGB(40,227,0,115)" runat="server"
                Style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 350px; width: 631px; margin-left: 0px;" 
                DataBinder=",,TemplateName:Detail;ValuePath:">
                <mrml:TVImage ID="TVImage2" runat="server" 
                    Style="position: absolute;  width: 240px; height: 340px; top: 6px; left: 5px;" 
                    DataPath="@img">
                </mrml:TVImage>  
                </mrml:TVListItemTemplate>
        </mrml:TVBoundList>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data>
  <listitems>
    <Entry img="img/Motorola_VIP1216E.png" title="VIP1216E" url="RCpage1.aspx?id=vip1216e" id="vip1216e">
      <Detail img="img/Motorola1_1.png">
        <Button title="Tlačidlo TV STB DVD" img="img/iptv1_tv_stb_dvd.png" popis="Výber príslušného zariadenia TV, STB alebo DVD"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Teletext" img="img/iptv1_teletext.png" popis="Zobrazí teletext" ></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo TV/Video" img="img/iptv1_tv_video.png" popis="Prepínanie medzi vstupmi TV" ></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Setup" img="img/iptv1_setup.png" popis="Naprogramovanie ovládača na ovládanie iných zariadení"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Power button" img="img/iptv1_power_btn.png" popis="Zapnúť/vypnúť Magio Box" ></Button>
      </Detail>
      <Detail img="img/Motorola1_2.png">
        <Button title="Tlačidlá 0-9" img="img/iptv1_0-9.png" popis="Zadávanie čísel kanálov/zadávanie písmen pri vyhľadávaní"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Mute" img="img/iptv1_mute.png" popis="Vypnutie/zapnutie zvuku" ></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Enter" img="img/iptv1_enter.png" popis="Potvrdiť zadaný údaj/zmena formátu obrazu"></Button>
      </Detail>
      <Detail img="img/Motorola1_3.png">
        <Button title="Tlačidlá Volume" img="img/iptv1_volume.png" popis="Ovládanie hlasitosti: hlasnejšie/tichšie"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Channel" img="img/iptv1_channel.png" popis="Prepínanie programov/ posúvanie v ponuke o jednu stranu"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Del" img="img/iptv1_del.png" popis="Vymazať zadaný údaj"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Menu" img="img/iptv1_menu.png" popis="Zobrazí hlavné menu"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Options" img="img/iptv1_options.png" popis="Ponúka doplnkové funkcie a služby"></Button>
      </Detail>
      <Detail img="img/Motorola1_4.png">
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Info" img="img/iptv1_info.png" popis="Zobrazí informácie o aktuálnom televíznom programe alebo o fi lme z Videopožičovne"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Guide" img="img/iptv1_guide.png" popis="Elektronický programový sprievodca"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Back" img="img/iptv1_back.png" popis="Návrat o krok alebo o stránku späť"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Exit" img="img/iptv1_exit.png" popis="Ukončí Magio Menu alebo spustenú aplikáciu"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo OK" img="img/iptv1_ok.png" popis="Potvrdenie výberu v ponuke"></Button>
      </Detail>
      <Detail img="img/Motorola1_5.png">
        <Button title="Ovládanie" img="" popis="Navigačné tlačidlá – používajú sa na pohyb v menu"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlá hore/dole" img="img/iptv1_up_down.png" popis="Tlačidlá hore/dole – prepínanie o kanál vyššie/nižšie v PIP"></Button>
        <Button title="Vysvetlenie_nothing" img="" popis=""></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlá doľava/doprava" img="img/left_right.png" popis="Tlačidlá doľava/doprava – prepínanie v zvolenom kanáli na predchádzajúci/ nasledujúci TV program"></Button>
      </Detail>
      <Detail img="img/Motorola1_6.png">
        <Button title="Multifunkčné tlačidlá" img="img/iptv1_farebne.png" popis="Multifunkčné tlačidlá"></Button>
        <Button title="Vysvetlenie_1" img="" popis="–na spúštanie/ ovládanie Magio aplikácií"></Button>
        <Button title="Vysvetlenie_2" img="" popis="–na prepínanie stránok v režime teletext"></Button>     
      </Detail>
      <Detail img="img/Motorola1_7.png">
        <Button title="Tlačidlá pretáčania " img="img/iptv1_forward_backward.png" popis="Pretáčanie dozadu alebo dopredu"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Play" img="img/iptv1_play.png" popis="Spustenie prehrávania pozastaveného programu"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Pause" img="img/iptv1_pause.png" popis="Pozastavenie prehrávaného programu"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Stop" img="img/iptv1_stop.png" popis="Zastavenie nahrávania alebo prehrávania"></Button>
        <Button title="Tlačidlo Record" img="img/iptv1_record.png" popis="Priame nahrávanie aktuálneho programu/ programovanie nahrávania"></Button>
      </Detail>
    </Entry>
```

I am sorry for my bad english, but I would really appreciate any help. I am stuck at this problem for a looong time, and it seems I am getting no results.

thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

DataBinder=",,TemplateName:Detail;ValuePath:"  I'm not sure about the ,,  I'm also new to media room.

With a visible count of 1, I'm not really sure that's OK.  Did you try setting all of the list items to the same number of items in each list and setting the visible count to the number of items (say 5)?

Sorry for the late answer.  I'd try that and see what you get.  Also, try the simplest possible example and go from there (1 list of items, say 5 items, and go from there).